# Does PostgresSQL have any default password policy?

Tags: postgresql, passwords

I've looked around and haven't found the basic Password requirements, if any, for PostgreSQL. That is, chars allowed, length, casing, etc...

Will someone please point me to these, if they exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do on the server is to use the [passwordcheck](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/passwordcheck.html) contrib module. You probably have to hack it up to fix your needs.

However, that won't be able to enforce password policies in general, because **the server never sees the clear text password** unless you change it with

```
ALTER ROLE xy PASSWORD 'clear_text';
```

which is **not** recommended. Changing the password with tools like `psql`'s `\password` command will hash the password **before** it is sent to the server, so the server cannot enforce any password rules.

You would have to check the **password on the client**, but naturally the client is not under your control, unless you restrict severely what people can do on their machines (and people usually find ways around such restrictions).

So there is really no way to do what you want.

What you *can* do is enable cracklib in the passwordcheck module and this way test the hashed passwords against a dictionary.

For good security, use something like LDAP or Kerberos authentication and implement your password policy there.

Comment: That seems odd, all we need is a set of rules under which pg will accept a password, we're not looking for the actual passwords or how to reverse engineer them. Redshift, a flavor of pg, has posted such rules: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_USER.html. Oh well, guess I'll only use [a-zA-Z] under 10 chars.

Comment: PostgreSQL is too secure to let you enforce a password policy: Typically, the server never sees the clear text password. Also, see the last sentence I added to the answer.